# Is there a better way to write this method?

Tags: java, methods

I want a *boolean method* that takes two arrays and returns **true** when the all the numbers in the first array there are in the second array. If at least one number doesn't match, then returns **false**.

Here is my code but something is off.

```
public static boolean noMoreRolls(int[] paramArrayOfInt1, int[] paramArrayOfInt2) {
    boolean test[] = new boolean[paramArrayOfInt1.length];
    int total = 0;      
    boolean end = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < paramArrayOfInt1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < paramArrayOfInt2.length; j++) {
            if (paramArrayOfInt1[i] == paramArrayOfInt2[j])
                test[i] = true;
        }
        if (test[i] == true)
            total++;
    }
    if (total == test.length) {
        end = true;
    }
    return end;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Sorry for the misleading and the wrong way to put the things down. The 2 arrays don't have the same length.
An example to understand my code: Array 1: [ 6, 6, 1, 2, 3,] / Array 2: [ 2 ,3 ], it should returns *false*.
Array 1: [ 2 ] / Array 2: [ 5, 5, 4, 4, 2], it should returns *true*.

Comment: `"Here is my code but something is off."` -- um,... what *exactly* is off? Please give us some indication about what exactly you're looking for, what do you mean by "better way".

Comment: More appropriate to codereview. In SO you shouldn't make vague statements about "something being off"

Comment: You're doing n**2 comparisons here, I would look into hashmaps personally.  Otherwise - as per other commenters - this question as it stands isn't suited to SO.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic: I think it should be migrated to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: First check for the length of arrays, if it is of different you can directly return false, does order matter in comparing if yes then sort and compare.

Comment: damnit guys, I just wrote a reply to this

Comment: This is a massively over-complicated approach. All you need is
`
    private boolean scanArray(int param, int[] array) {
        for (int i: array)
           if (i == param)
              return true;
        return false;
    }

    public boolean noMoreRolls(int[] arr1, int[] arr2) {
        if (arr1.length != arr2. length) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i: arr1) {
            if (!scanArray(i, arr2) {
                return false;
            }
        } 
        return true;
    }
`

Comment: You will need to take the code out of the comment and format it somewhere readable.

Comment: OK sorry for the bad writing. I have notice in my main code sometimes the result should be true but it's false. Second I think that the code could be much more simpler.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies of you guys. And thanks Tim too for his effort.

Answer (score 2):

Use Java.util.Arrays

```
int[] paramArrayOfInt1={1,2};
int[] paramArrayOfInt2={1,3};
if(paramArrayOfInt1.length==paramArrayOfInt2.length) {
    if(!Arrays.equals(paramArrayOfInt1, paramArrayOfInt2)) {
        System.out.println("False");
    } else{
        System.out.println("True");
    }
    } else {
        System.out.println("False");
    }
```

Comment: That won't work, the elements need to be in order as well as matching for Array.equals.

Comment: The OP wants to see whether all elements of `a` are in `b` but not necessarily the converse. This requires that `a` and `b` are _exactly the same_.

Comment: No this isn't going to work. First of all my array1 and array2 doesn't have the same length. I knew that way but it doesn't work for my code.